# Ошибка инициализации Vuforia

Tags: unity3d, vuforia

На компьютере ошибка инициализации появляется от раза к разу а на iPhone теперь вообще камера запускаться не хочет. Я думал что наверное это из за устаревшей версии Vuforia, но после обновления эта проблема не исчезла.

Как можно решить проблему с ошибкой инициализации Vuforia ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, где твои скриншоты?
Во-вторых, какая версия и у Vuforia, и у Unity, и у, собственно, самого iPhone? Обычно такая фигня из-за [конфликта версий](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Vuforia-Supported-Versions).
Можешь почитать топики на форуме Vuforia. Вот [один из них](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-extension-technical-discussion/vuforia-initialization-error-when-switching-scene-unity).

В крайнем случае, можешь попробовать переустановить [Unity вместе с Vuforia](https://store.unity.com/ru/download/thank-you?thank-you=personal&os=win&nid=834), а затем создать новый проект, в который ты закинешь нужные скрипты и/или ресурсы со старого.

Comment: Версия Vuforia 7.2.25 , версия Unity 2018.2.1f1 Personal а версия IOS 11.4 (iPhone 6s).
Переустановка Unity и Vuforia ни чем не помогло.

Вот ссылка на скриншот: https://www.dropbox.com/l/scl/AADLJnbv4FMEsELbu8MbCQdWJ51qkFWlsoI

Comment: @AsifMamedov Ты можешь скинуть скрин файла VuforiaConfiguration? А то у меня есть некоторые подозрения, судя по ошибкам в консоли. P.S. Файл находится в папке Resources по умолчанию. Можешь также воспользоваться поиском в Unity. Если файл не нашёл - просто добавь AR-камеру к сцене; потом файл должен заспавниться.

Comment: Вот фото VuforiaConfiguration: https://www.dropbox.com/l/scl/AAAjColz-j8bWv7oOhbGrTCkS2tX4yIW5bk
https://www.dropbox.com/l/scl/AADMD3qrkN4DCNJKTTzoXCVSO54s8o7_eLA

Comment: Хм. Окей. Попробуй во вкладке "Webcam" отключить настройки (верхняя галочка), когда будешь билдить приложение на телефон. Читал, что у некоторых сработало. Можешь также попробовать скачать SDK для iOS (https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/sdk).

Comment: Вот еще одна ссылка: [ссылка](dropbox.com/l/scl/AADMD3qrkN4DCNJKTTzoXCVSO54s8o7_eLA )

Comment: Окей-окей, я увидел. Попробуй то, что я написал выше.

Comment: Есть результаты?

Comment: Да! Спасибо )))